# Remote connection to MySQL works via command line, but fails when using php's mysql_connect from a web browser

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I am trying to connect to a MySQL server using PHP's 'mysql_connect()' function, but the connection fails. This is my code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("example.net", "myusername","") or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
```

I placed this code inside a PHP script, which I try to open using a web browser (the script is stored on a remote host which has PHP enabled) but it doesn't work. It doesn't return the `die` error either. Echoing something before the `$con` successfully outputs in the browser,  whereas nothing outputs after that line. If I type:

```
mysql -h example.net -u myusername
```

from a remote machine, I could connect to the DB without any problem and do queries and other modifications.

Update : 
I also tried this after some suggestion, but no improvement:

```
<?php
    $usern = "myusername";
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=servername.net;dbname=test', $usern, "");
    echo $usern;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What operating system is the remote host running PHP using? Perhaps MySQL isn't enabled in `php.ini`. Also, please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) (see the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)). Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you care to learn, [this is a good PDO tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Have you tried using PDO or the MySQLi interface? If you're trying to learn PHP, you *should not be using the mysql_** functions regardless. See if you can access the database by using a line similar to this:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

If you need more detailed documentation, this code comes directly from the [documentation itself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

EDIT: Also, try using PDO's error checking functionality. This example creates a database connection using PDO and tries to perform a simple query. It doesn't use prepared statements or any of those features, so it's not production-ready code (i.e. *don't just throw this into your code without understanding how to improve it) and you'll need to edit it to include a `SELECT` query that's relevant to your database, but it should at least tell PDO to provide more information about the errors it encounters.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "admin";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// query
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM booksa";
$q = $conn->query($sql) or die("ERROR: " . implode(":", $conn->errorInfo()));

$r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($r);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I switched to the new code you mentioned, but that doesn't solve the problem I have. I tried this simple file : 

<?php                                                                                                                             $usern = "myusername";                                                                    
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=server;dbname=test', $usern, "");                                                         
echo $usern;                                  
?> 

It doesn't printout the $usern in the browser.

Comment: @iamauser Does it show an error message? Can you post the PDO code that you used (you can post it by editing your question)?

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow asking questions. Could you please let me know the correct formatting to write code: Here is the code I used.
<?php $usern = "myusername"; $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=server;dbname=test', $usern, ""); echo $usern; ?>

Comment: @iamauser Edit your question and put that code in, since it's difficult to read in the comments. From what I can tell, you don't define `server` (nor is it a variable name in the string, since that would be `$server`). It's easier if you click "Edit" directly underneath your question and copy the code in to a new section in your question.

Comment: I did now. Please check. The servername I replaced with some dummy name when I post it here. About your question whether it returns any error, no it doesn't retrurn any error, just a blank white screen.

Comment: I don't know what exactly happened, but the same code give me the printouts of the 'echo $usern' and connects the test db. Next, I have to change my whole code to replace mysql_* with the PDO syntax. I hope after it works, otherwise I will get back with more question. Thanks for this anyways.

Comment: @iamauser If that code works, you should accept this answer so others can learn from it. Also, you should *definitely* replace the `mysql_*` statements in your code for reasons of security and efficiency. You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark underneath the numbers of votes.

Answer (score 1):

Is the php file located on the same server as the mysql database, if so you might have to use 'localhost' as the first argument for mysql_connect() instead the external address.

Comment: Hi, The php file is located in another server (web-hosting server), so localhost doesn't work. I realize that web-host doesn't have the php-mysql connection, i.e. If I execute the php file via command line on the 'web-host', it fails with the following error : PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect(). Can this be the reason ?

Comment: yes, that can be the reason! most likely your hosting plan does not support the php mysql module... try to put a phpinfo(); there and see if mysqli or mysql is loaded.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not you can get `mysql_connect` working, you *should not be using it.* Please read the entire paragraph that I posted for the exact reasons why. Even though you may "just want to get something working" this is not an acceptable reason to use a deprecated, insecure set of functions like the `mysql_*` functions.